# Windows 7 - Open Command Prompt Window

Tags: windows-7, cmd.exe

The CMD function is supposed to open a new command prompt window, however in Windows 7, it opens another inside of the existing one so if you typed in exit, it will simple exit the most recent one started. Is there a way to make CMD open a new window?

Comment: It does this in all versions of Windows AFAIK. Anyway, this isn't a programming question.

Comment: I think you better ask this question at super user. Link is http://superuser.com

Comment: Technically this is 'batch' programming: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Batch_file Also, this is for a script so it is in fact coding related.

Answer (score 4):

Using *start* may or may not work, I can't recall and don't have Windows handy:

```
start cmd
```

OTOH, win+R (to bring up the Run dialog) then "cmd" will always do what you want.

Comment: I'm doing this from a script so Win-R wouldn't work, however start works just fine.