# How to delete folder named "..." on Windows

Tags: windows, cmd.exe

How can a folder named ... be deleted on Windows 10?

Note that the folder name is three dots.

```
C:\Users\Mike the Coder God\Documents\Embarcadero\Studio>dir
 Volume in drive C is Windows
 Volume Serial Number is B0D9-0617

 Directory of C:\Users\Mike the Coder God\Documents\Embarcadero\Studio

02/09/2022  09:31 PM    <DIR>          .
02/09/2022  09:31 PM    <DIR>          ..
08/23/2020  11:45 AM    <DIR>          ...
02/21/2018  10:50 AM    <DIR>          19.0
11/08/2018  04:50 PM    <DIR>          20.0
02/09/2022  09:31 PM    <DIR>          code_templates
02/09/2022  05:35 PM    <DIR>          projects
               0 File(s)              0 bytes
               7 Dir(s)  620,393,701,376 bytes free

C:\Users\Mike the Coder God\Documents\Embarcadero\Studio>
```

I've tried running CMD as an administrator and entering this command:

```
rmdir "\\?\C:\Users\Mike the Coder God\Documents\Embarcadero\Studio\..."
```

It responds with: **The directory is not empty.**

Entering these commands does nothing. (The folder/prompt stay the same.)

```
cd ... 

cd "..."
```

Entering this command gets **The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.**

```
rmdir .\...
```

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/528502/cant-remove-three-dots-folder-on-my-hdd

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can't remove three dots folder on my hdd](https://superuser.com/questions/528502/cant-remove-three-dots-folder-on-my-hdd)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it is not empty, use `rmdir /s /q` to delete its contents recursively.

```
rd/s/q \\?\C:\etc\etc\...
```

Suffixing the path with `\` would also bypass the stripping of trailing `.`'s.

```
rd/s/q ...\
```